# Getting Garbage value while convert into long Objective -C

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion, nsstring, long-integer

I am trying to convert `NSString` to `long` but I am getting garbage value. Below is my code :

```
long t1 = [[jsonDict valueForKeyPath:@"detail.amount"]doubleValue] * 1000000000000000000;
long t2 = [[jsonDict valueForKeyPath:@"detail.fee"]doubleValue] * 10000000000000000;  
NSLog(@"t1: %ld",t1);
NSLog(@"t2: %ld",t2);
```

**detail.amout = 51.74

detail.fee = 2.72**

> O/P :
>   t1: 9223372036854775807   (Getting Garbage value here)
>   t2: 27200000000000000  (Working fine)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is out of the range of long

Comment: So will double solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Each number types (int, long, double, float) has limits. For your long 64 bit (because your device is 64bit) number the upper limit is :9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

In your case, 51.74 * 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 =

```
51,740,000,000,000,000,000
```

While Long **64bit** only has a maximum of

```
9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

So an overflow happens at 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and above. Which is what your calculation evaluates into.

Also to note, that what you are doing will also cause problem if you only cater for 64bit long range, because what happens when your app runs on a 32bit (like iPhone 5c or below)?

Generally a bad idea to use large numbers, unless you're doing complex maths. If number accuracies are not critical, then you should consider simplifying the number like 51,740G (G = Giga). etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're storing the **product** to `long` type variables `t1` and `t2`.

Use either `float` or `double`, and you'll get the correct answer.

Based on C's data types:

> Long signed integer type. Capable of containing at least the
>   [−2,147,483,647, +2,147,483,647] range; thus, it is at least 32
>   bits in size.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Answer (score 0):

9223372036854775807 is the maximum value of a 64-bit signed `long`. I deduce that `[[jsonDict valueForKeyPath:@"detail.amount"]doubleValue] * 1000000000000000000` is larger than the maximum `long` value, so when you cast it to `long`, you get the closest value that `long` can represent.

Answer (score 0):

As you read, it is not possible with `long`. Since it looks like you do finance math, you should use `NSDecimalNumber` instead of `double` to solve that problem.